# Pandas with nested JSON objects

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have following dataset:

```
 {'Result': {
            'j': {'confirmed': true, 'version': '1'},
            'z': {'confirmed': false, 'version': '2'},
            'y': {'confirmed': true, 'version': '3'}
            },
         'D': 'null'
        }
```

And I need a table with columns : name (values j, z, y goes there) and confirmed (true or false goes there).

The closest thing I have tried is pd.Series(df), but it gives me something like:

```
j                    {'confirmed': true, 'version': '1'}
z                    {'confirmed': false, 'version': '2'}
```

How can I achieve only two accurate named columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` with `orient='index'`, then `reset_index()` and `rename()` to set the previous index as column `'name'`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset['Result'], orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'name'})
```

Yields:

```
   name confirmed version
0     j      true       1
1     y      true       3
2     z     false       2
```

Comment: That's how I'd do it (-: